# How to Convert any XML file to a Data Frame?

Tags: r

I imported an XML file into R.  I did a little parsing on the data because it was really messy.  Now, I have a slightly cleaner data set, called 'doc', and I am trying to export it, but I'm getting all kinds of errors.

I tried this:

```
library(rvest)
df<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//outputColumn"))
```

I got this:

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"
```

I tried this:

```
write.csv(doc, file = "C:\\path_here\\MyData.csv")
```

I got this:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("xml_document", "xml_node")" to a data.frame
```

I tried this:

```
write.table(doc, "C:\\path_here\\filename.txt, sep="\t", col.names=F)
```

I got this:

```
Error: unexpected input in "write.table(doc, "C:\\path_here\\filename.txt, sep="\"
```

Is there a way to simplify this, so I can just get everything into a DataFrame, and export it?  Or, just dump everything into a text file.  That would be fine too.  Thanks.

'outputColumn refId='
'DTS:refId='
'/outputColumns'

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
truncationRowDisposition="FailComponent"/><outputColumn refId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[DEF_TAX_AMT]" dataType="i4" errorOrTruncationOperation="Conversion" errorRowDisposition="FailComponent" externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].ExternalColumns[DEF_TAX_AMT]" lineageId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[DEF_TAX_AMT]" name="DEF_TAX_AMT" truncationRowDisposition="FailComponent"/><outputColumn refId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[OTS_BALANCE]" dataType="numeric" errorOrTruncationOperation="Conversion" errorRowDisposition="FailComponent" externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].ExternalColumns[OTS_BALANCE]" lineageId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[OTS_BALANCE]" name="OTS_BALANCE" precision="19" scale="2" truncationRowDisposition="FailComponent"/>
```

I want to pull out this part:

```
refId="Package\Pre RawData\108_DataPull\108_1T2_Multi_MG_FUTURE\108_MULTI_MG_FUTURE.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[DEF_TAX_AMT]"
```

If I can just aggregate everything between the quotes on the line with 'outputColumn refId=' to a list, and export the list to a file (CSV, TXT, or whatever), that would be awesome.  Similarly, if I can aggregate with 'DTS:refId=' to a list, and export it, that would be great.

Comment: No two single XML files have to be same dimension or structure. It is an open-ended, nested data type left to designer unlike dataframes/datasets that are always two-dimensional, rows by columns. So a generalizable conversion of *any* XML to df is not possible. We need to see your specific XML to tailor accordingly. Show us *doc*.

Comment: Yes, yes, that makes sense.  Well, can I pull out strings that match some patterns like these? 'outputColumn refId=' or 'DTS:refId=' or '/outputColumns' If I could create a smaller list based on a few patterns of strings, it would help immensely!  The XML is around 35MB and it is just a lot to get through.

Comment: Please post simplified, shortened version of XML enough to know its repeating pattern. Always include root in case of namespaces which you show.

Comment: Ok.  I just updated my original post.

Comment: That is still a truncated, incomplete XML. Please provide at least root.